# How to install Microsoft Bot Framework tools in pipeline and then use

Tags: botframework

Can anyone provide a YAML example of how to install the Microsoft Bot Framework CLI tools in an Azure pipeline and then use them with the PowerShell script https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/templates/csharp/VA/VA/Deployment/Scripts/update_cognitive_models.ps1 in https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions?

Comment: Have you just tried simply running the command `npm install -g @microsoft/botframework-cli` and then using any of the `bf` commands that you want to use? (Like `bf --version` for simple test) See [botframework-cli repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use NPM task to install the tool and then use a standard command line task to execute your commands. It should look like this:

```
steps:
(...)
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install -g @microsoft/botframework-cli'
    verbose: true
- task: CmdLine@1
  inputs:
    script: 'bf {your-command-here}'
(...)
```